# Davening Twice by Mistake

Tags: halacha, tefilla, mistakes

What should one do if he mistakenly davens (e.g. Mincha) a second time, and remembers half way through Shemoneh Esrei?

Comment: A twist on the question:  If you finished, would it be a shaila of being yotze maariv?  (Either after plag or acc. to the Aruch Hashulchan)

Comment: @YDK I doubt it...In the case of Tashlumin, if you prayed the first prayer having mind for that to be Tashlumin- you are not Yose Yede Hova either Tefilot. I would **think** the same applies here.

Comment: @Vram if you had in mind for the second one to be regular Tefila, then all you have to do is another tashlumim. However, if the first Tefila you had in mind a Tashlumim and then found out that you weren't supposed to, you must repeat another 2 S"E's/

Comment: @HachamGabriel, that's not because you need the proper tefilah in mind.  It is because the prayer that you designate for tashlumim must be attached (follow) to another tefila and that is lacking in your case.

Comment: @YDK http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38907

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't consider it a tefillas nedavah (voluntary prayer), because you started it under the impression that it was required. So you simply break off wherever you are holding.

(Shmuel in [Berachos 21a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=21&format=pdf); Shulchan Aruch, [Orach Chaim 107:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=262))

Answer (score 0):

On your twist: If you realized in the middle and it is an acceptable time to daven maariv, it seems from the Shaarei Tshuva siman 422 that you can have kavana that this tfilah be for maariv and you would be yotzei maariv.

The case in the shaarei tshuva is if one begins to daven mussaf on rosh chodesh, and realizes after the first three brachos that he has not davened shacharis, he should use this tfilah to daven shacharis and then daven mussaf afterwards. From here it seems one could substitute one tfilas chovah for another, even though it is clear from the mishanh brurah in the other answer to this question that you can't substitute a nedavah for a chovah.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thank you for the answer. Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). For general help see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Maariv may not be a Chovah, though, in the same way as Mincha.