# Led the prayers in error forgetting he had already prayed. Can he continue?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader

What do the sources have to say about the following situation? A person helps to make a minyan for  mincha at the earliest possible time on a long summer's day. He forgets that he did this and goes to synagogue for his regular mincha minyan. He is asked to lead the prayers and only after saying the quiet Amidah realises that he has already prayed.

Can he continue to repeat the Amidah on the grounds that this will be to fulfil the obligation of anyone in the community who does not know how to pray or should he stand down and get someone to replace him.

related: [Said mincha twice: now what?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38907/said-mincha-twice-now-what)

Comment: OC 124:2 implies he can continue and say the repetition, but in a case where someone else is available that doesn't mean he should.

Comment: @DoubleAA Please explain how OC124:2 is relevant to my case of someone having davenned Amidah in error.

Comment: You don't have to have prayed with the Tzibbur to lead the repetition